# Unable to get property 'textContent' of undefined or null reference in IE11 and Edge

Tags: javascript

```
function MainfillTable(table, srcs) 
{

var cols = 0
for (field in srcs) 
{
    srcs[cols] = field
    cols++
}  

var row
for (row = 0; row < srcs[srcs[0]].length; row++) 
{
    var tr = trtemplate.cloneNode(true)
    
    var data Fields = new Array()
    var elements = tr.getElementsByTagName('*')
    
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
        var element = elements[i]
        if (element.hasAttribute('data'))
        {
            var dataFieldName = element.getAttribute('data')

            var dataFieldValue = srcs[dataFieldName][row].textContent

            if (element.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'div')
                element.innerHTML = dataFieldValue
            else if (element.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input')
                element.value = dataFieldValue
        
    }
    
}
}
```

Getting Issue in Line (`var dataFieldValue = srcs[dataFieldName][row].textContent`) as

```
IE11 - Unable to get property 'textContent' of undefined or null reference
Edge - Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined
```

Can anyone please help what is breaking the code?

Comment: Your error would imply that `srcs[dataFieldName][row]` is `null` or `undefined`. Have you checked that it exists? What is `srcs`?

Comment: var srcs = new Array() and for srcs[dataFieldName][row] , we are getting proper value for each element , but throwing error only for textContent and its working fine in IE7 to IE9.

Comment: Have you made a `console.log (srcs[dataFieldName][row])`, just to see if it has an property `textContent`?

Comment: **we are getting proper value for each element** whats the value? can you show some of the data.

Comment: *If the node is a document or a Doctype, textContent returns null.* - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Comment: srcs -->Array(50) ,datafieldName=each element  in the srcs array,row=0 and increases .

Comment: I have tried using let instead of var in the above link but still getting issue.